# MySQL says table is there, then says it's not

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1146

check the database-generating sql (looks fine):

```
CREATE TABLE `HourOfDay` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hourString` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

check the file system (it's there):

```
# ls -al Mycomp_test | grep -i hour
-rw-rw----    1 _mysql  wheel      0 Mar  1 08:13 HourOfDay.MYD
-rw-rw----    1 _mysql  wheel   1024 Mar  1 08:13 HourOfDay.MYI
-rw-rw----    1 _mysql  wheel   8598 Mar  1 08:13 HourOfDay.frm
```

check the database (looks good):

```
»mysql -u root Mycomp_test -e 'show tables' | grep -i hour
HourOfDay
```

check the database table (oops wtf!?):

```
»mysql -u root Mycomp_test -e 'show create table HourOfDay'
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1: Table 'mycomp_test.hourofday' doesn't exist
```

**UPDATE**:  More info

- This is an OSX system running mysql-5.1.38-osx10.5-x86_64
- If I drop the database and recreate it I get the same error (it's reliably reproducible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8.2.2. [Identifier Case Sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

```
»cat /etc/my.cnf 
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names=2
```

Comment: I would try lower_case_table_named=0

Comment: Does it work fine with tables with all lowercase names? 
CREATE TABLE `hourofday` if so this isn't the issue.

Answer (score 1):

"`Table 'mycomp_test.hourofday' doesn't exist`" is suspicious, as it should be `HourOFDay` on a unix/linux system.

Comment: Is it all unix/linux or is there a windows system filesharing with a linux/unix system?